# Strange APK Behaviour - Only when downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Im in a state where I really dont know what to do, it would be great if someone could help me out ! Thanks In Advance.

When I made a signed apk from the android studio and put it directly onto my phone it worked perfectly fine, even in other devices. But after uploading it onto the play store (open beta) and then downloaded it via the link to test, the following happens.

**On cellular**

- The app seams to work fine, the flow -> Splash Screen -> onboarding screen -> Login in Screen -> Home Screen

**Now the problem when I switch to WIFI**
 -

- White Screen -> Black Screen -> White Screen -> Splash Screen -> On
  Boarding Screen (comes, and skips to the login screen) -> Login ->
  home Screen

but when I go into application in the settings menu of android and clear cache and then open the app it works fine.

*Do let me know if there is a work around, Thanks ! Cheers*

Comment: Obviously you have an error in your code. Clearing the cache helps, meaning the problem might be with SharedPreferences. Or may be your onResume or onWindowFocusChanged is wrongly implemented.

Comment: @edgehog.net - Thank-you for for the reply, will definitely look into it and revert. Appreciate the swift reply, Cheers !